# How do you say "it is becoming evening / it is getting evening"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Not "it is evening", not "in the evening", not "it is getting late". I wanted to translate a famous quote and I was thinking something like:

聞け、夕方なっている

But I think it sounds more "the evening is becoming []"

Comment: Is “it is becoming evening” the entire quote?

Comment: The entire quote is "listen, it is becoming evening". It's a kind of sinesthesia: noticing the coming of evening by its sounds ("listen")

Comment: Is *is becoming evening* totally natural as English? I guess, in Japanese, 夕方 and progressive of any verb won't come together.

Comment: This is a famous quote? Google has no results for "listen, it is becoming evening" (as an exact string)

Comment: Both good observations. The original sentence is in Italian ("ascolta, si fa sera"). I feel that my English translation is already a bit clunky

Comment: Even if that contains a kind of progressive aspect, it is in present tense, right? Likewise, in Japanese one would say もう夕方になる = It (will) become evening (already).

Comment: Thank you, I think it gives the sense.